# Standard input/output in Pyclewn(GDB front end for vim)

Tags: c++, linux, debugging, vim, gdb

I've just installed Pyclewn. It works and shows variables and etc. But it doesn't show my program's output and when my program wants to input something, it doesn't do anything(I can write ":C run output" and it works. but not with standard I/O.
There was something in its documentation: http://pyclewn.sourceforge.net/_static/pyclewn.html
But I didn't understand what it says.

P.S: I've done that. Now I want to map for example  to run those commands. but because the "nn" in /dev/pts/nn may vary, I should manually enter the number(see it from the xterm opened). I also have another problem when I map a key to a sequence of gdb commands, it says gdb is busy, I can add ":sleep 100m" between commands and the problem will be soved. but in the documentation it says that I should enable async option. but when I run pyclewn from vim with :Pyclewn command I don't know how to enable the async option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `inferior_tty.py` to create a terminal to be used with the program being debugged.

Abridged summary (most relevant bits only) from [the FAQ](http://pyclewn.sourceforge.net/faq.html#standard-error-output-in-gdb-console):

```
:Cshell setsid xterm -e inferior_tty.py &
```

Determine what the name of the tty to be used is from this newly spawned window, then:

```
:Cset inferior-tty /dev/pts/nn
```

Answer (score 1):

Or just start `pyclewn` from a terminal and it will automatically grab that terminal for input and output.

E.g:

```
  pyclewn -c "main.cc other.h other.cc"
```